# regex expression extract string after last comma with no numbers

Tags: python, regex, expression

Given a dataframe `A` that looks like this:

| id | information |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Yellow, in town, John |
| 002 | Green, home, Lia 33 |
| 003 | Yellow, garden, Peter2543 |
| 004 | Red, 23 garden, 004 John891 |
| 005 | Red, home, 245Sarah |
| 006 | Red 2, park 28, 67 Luke |
| 007 | Purple 03, to the beach, Mary Rose 9855 |
| ... | ... |

I want to create a new column called `name` by extracting the name from `information`, without numbers. That is:

| id | information | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Yellow, in town, John | John |
| 002 | Green, wardrobe, home, Lia 33 | Lia |
| 003 | Yellow, garden, Peter2543 | Peter |
| 004 | Red, 23 garden, 004 John891 | John |
| 005 | Red, hat, home, 245Sarah | Sarah |
| 006 | Red 2, park 28, 67 Luke | Luke |
| 007 | Purple 03, to the beach, Mary Rose 9855 | Mary Rose |
| ... | ... | ... |

Notice that:

- the name in `information` is always after the last comma
- the name may have numbers after and/or before the name
- these numbers can be separated by a white space or not
- the name can be two words (i.e. *Mary Rose*)

If I do:

```
A['name'] = A['information'].apply(lambda x: x.rsplit(',', 1)[1] if ',' in x else x)
```

it returns everything after the last comma (i.e: *John*, *Lia 33*, *Peter 2543*,...). But I need to only get the name.

I guess I have to use `re.split()` instead but I cannot figure out which should be the regex expression...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"information":["Yellow, in town, John","Green, home, Lia 33","Yellow, garden, Peter2543","Red, 23 garden, 004 John891","Red, home, 245Sarah","Red 2, park 28, 67 Luke","Purple 03, to the beach, Mary Rose 9855"]})
df['name'] = df['information'].str.extract(r'.*,\s*(?:\d+\s*)?([^\d,]+?)(?:\s*\d+)?$', expand=False)
```

Output:

```py
>>> df['information'].str.extract(r'.*,\s*(?:\d+\s*)?([^\d,]+?)(?:\s*\d+)?$', expand=False)
0         John
1          Lia
2        Peter
3         John
4        Sarah
5         Luke
6    Mary Rose
Name: information, dtype: object
```

*Details*:

- `.*,` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then a `,` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:\d+\s*)?` - an optional sequence of one or more digits and then zero or more whitespaces
- `([^\d,]+?)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than digits and comma, as few as possible
- `(?:\s*\d+)?` - an optional sequence of zero or more whitespaces and then one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.